# VirusTotal Upload File

Tags: node.js, api

I am following the documentation in https://developers.virustotal.com/v3.0/reference#file trying to analyze files through VirusTotal API using the endpoint `https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/files` but it keeps throwing the following error:

```
{"error": {        
    "message": "Received file with an empty filename. Please post with filename.",
    "code": "BadRequestError"\n    
   }
}
```

The code I'm using is really simple, and I have change it adding more keys in the data object like: "name",  filename", and so on but seems nothing is working:

```
class VirusTotal {
  constructor(){
    this.APIKEY = CONF.virus_apikey;
  }
  async checkFile(path){
    let url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/files';
    let header = {'x-apikey': this.APIKEY};
    let data = {file:path, name: path.split('/')[path.split('/').length -1], filename: 'asdasd'};
    REQUEST(url, ['post'], data, (err, res, status, headers) => {
      console.log(err, res, status, headers);
    }, null, header);
  }
}
```

Then I tried to do it through the GUI they have to test, but didn't work either, throwing the same error.

[image: Virus Total Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload a file to their API it reaquires a to read the file, pass it as a Buffer and stringify it.
I got the next solution:

```
  async analyzeFile(path, fileType){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let file = require('fs').readFileSync(path);
      const Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
      if (typeof input=="string") file = Buffer.from(file, 'utf8')
      if (Buffer.isBuffer(file)) file = file;
      file = JSON.stringify(file);
      const request = require('request');
      request({
        url: 'https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/files',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'x-apikey': this.APIKEY},
        formData: {file: {value: file, options: {filename: path.split('/')[path.split('/').length -1], filetype: fileType}}},
      }, async (err, res) => {
        !err ? resolve(res) : reject(err);
      });

    });
  }
```

As well, per VirusTotal staff the GUI they has a bug, therefore it doesn't work.